# How to use stack navigator and bottom navigator in a React native expo app

Tags: javascript, react-native, stack-navigator

I am developing a react-native application using expo cli, where I use `bottomTabNavigator` (which works fine) and the `stackNavigator`.

The application consists of 5 screens, which are navigated with the `bottomTabNavigator`, and of these five screens 2 need the `stackNavigator`.

For the implementation of the stack navigator I read the react native documentation, and reported in the project the example code that is on the documentation, to test the correct integration with my application.
My problem arises from the fact that importing the stack navigator into the actual screen where I need it, I am not shown any error messages, but neither do the navigation buttons of my test stack navigator appear.

Do you have any advice or suggestions as to why?

- my stack navigator code : `StackN.js`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen({navigation}){
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Button title="Go to Profile" onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Profile')} />
        </View>
    );
}

function ProfileScreen({navigation}){
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Button title="Go to Notifications" onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Profile')} />
            <Button title="Go Back" onPress={()=>navigation.goBack()} />
        </View>
    );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
    return(
        <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

export default function App() {
    
    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
            <MyStack />
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

- screen where I import the stack navigator

```
import * as  React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Platform, Button,TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground, Dimensions, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import Colors from '../constants/Colors';
import { Ionicons, MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import ClubDetails from '../components/clubcomponents/ClubDetails';
import HeaderComponent from '../components/commoncomponents/HeaderComponent';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import StackN from '../navigations/StackN';

const ClubDetailScreen = props => {

    return (
        <View>
            <HeaderComponent />
            <View>
                <ScrollView style={{height:100}}>
                   <Text>SCHERMATA NON DIRETTAMENTE COLLEGATA ALL'IMPLEMENTAZIONE ATTUALE :  - TODO - </Text>
                </ScrollView>
                <NavigationContainer>
                    <StackN />
                </NavigationContainer> 
            </View>
        </View>
        
    );
}

//opzioni di navigazione della pagina


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header:{ 
        marginTop:27,
        height: 50,
        backgroundColor: Colors.primary
    },
    text:{
        
    },
    icon: {
        marginTop: 14,
        marginLeft:3
    },
    title: {
        marginVertical: -35,
        fontSize: 20,
        fontStyle: 'italic',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'white',
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    avatar: {
        marginLeft: Dimensions.get('window').width - 40,
        marginTop: 7,
        color: 'white'
    },
    dropdown:{
        marginRight: 40,
    }
});

export default ClubDetailScreen;
```

Comment: I follow this link, and i also expo, my app run well https://reactnavigation.org//blog/2020/01/29/using-react-navigation-5-with-react-native-paper/

Comment: Hi @LinhNguyễnNgọc, i've followed the link but doesen't exist the page...

Comment: you change // to /, i used airdrop to send link, i dont know why the have two / https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2020/01/29/using-react-navigation-5-with-react-native-paper/